# List files using regex in bash | ignore file having certain characters

Tags: regex, bash

I am new to regex, I want to list file matching with given regex.
I have some samples files as shown in below picture

[image]

I want regex which should return below mentioned files:

test1.csv
test2.csv
test3.csv
test9.csv.tt

I want to use the find command for this and i also tried with below mentioned find command but could not achive my expected results

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "**test[0-9]*[^-a-zA-Z_]***.csv*" -exec ls -l {} +
```

I want to use same commnad to achieve my expected output only i want correct regex.

Anyone have any idea please do help!

Comment: You can only use a glob pattern in `-name`. You need `-regex` and a pattern that will match the full path. Like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*/test[0-9]\{1,\}\.csv.*' -exec ls -l {} +`. Or, the regex might be `\(.*/\)\{0,1\}test[0-9]\{1,\}\.csv.*`

Comment: Well, I see that `find . -type f -regex '.*/test[0-9]+\.csv.*'` works already fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`, you can try:

`find . -type f -regex ./test[0-9]\*.csv.\* -exec ls -l {} +`

Or, using `sed`, you can try

`$ ls -l | sed '/^d/d;/ test[0-9]*\.csv.*/!d'`

(not sure if digits are mandatory -- if they're, then replace `*` by `+`)

There are 2 commands in this `sed`.

1. `/^d/d` deletes any row that starts with a `d` (exclude directories)
2. `/ test[0-9]*\.csv.*/!d` removes any row that doesn't match the regex you want to filter by.

Comment: Note that `ls | sed` (or `ls | ...anything...`) is generally [frowned on for good reasons](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).